# How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This [question also has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700648/escape-percentage-sign-db2-sql), but it mentions DB2 specifically.

How do I search for a **string** using `LIKE` that already has a percent `%` symbol in it? The `LIKE` operator uses `%` symbols to signify wildcards.

Answer (score 349, accepted):

Use brackets. So to look for 75%

```
WHERE MyCol LIKE '%75[%]%'
```

This is simpler than ESCAPE and common to most RDBMSes.

Comment: also note you do not have to escape a percent symbol in other constructs such as a user function, concatenation, etc.

Comment: [Can give better cardinality estimates (and hence execution plans) too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18696341/73226)

Comment: You can escape also the underscore wildcard character too: `[_]`. How do you escape the open square bracket then? Like this: `[[]`. http://www.sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html

Comment: Using the ESCAPE clause is easier to understand than MS's brain-damaged quoting mechanism.

Answer (score 61):

You can use the `ESCAPE` keyword with `LIKE`. Simply prepend the desired character (e.g. '!') to each of the existing `%` signs in the string and then add `ESCAPE '!'` (or your character of choice) to the end of the query.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM prices
WHERE discount LIKE '%80!% off%' ESCAPE '!'
```

This will make the database treat 80% as an actual part of the string to search for and not 80(wildcard).

[Documentation on `LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql)

Comment: The line breaking of the query-sample suggests as the ESCAPE clause were part of the SELECT statement. Based on the documentation it should be part of the LIKE clause, meaning, you could theoreticcaly use different ESCAPE clauses in the conditions in the WHERE block, if you happen to need different escape chars.

Answer (score 17):

```
WHERE column_name LIKE '%save 50[%] off!%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code below to find a specific value.

```
WHERE col1 LIKE '%[%]75%'
```

When you want a single digit number after the% sign, you can write the following code.

```
WHERE col2 LIKE '%[%]_'
```