# Percentage sign (%) in an INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, escaping

I have to change values into my database. One of the string values can contain a `%` sign.

Rough example:

```
UPDATE Mortgage 
SET TEXT = 'The interest rate is 7%';
```

The change is not saved in the database. How can I escape the percentage sign in SQL Server

Comment: How do you interact with the database? Using an IDE/Client or self-written software?

Comment: It is normal SQL Server query. It should work correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql)

Comment: @RB., Above question is about escaping `%` in `LIKE` operator...

Comment: If you are really using SQL Server, you don't need to quote the % sign!

Comment: @Rilie Please mark as answer the one you think answers your question. It always helps both for you for future questions and for the ones who are answering as well...

Comment: Perhaps there is a `CHECK` constraint preventing values containing `%` characters and is generating an error that is not being exposed to your call.

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE Mortgage SET TEXT = 'The interest rate is 7' + CHAR(37);
```

37 is the decimal [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for a percent symbol.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom escape character, for example:

```
UPDATE Mortgage 
SET TEXT = 'The interest rate is 7\%' ESCAPE '\';
```

But I think you didn't need to escape this character `%` here becouse it has no special meaning as an input value, but you have to escape it in case you want to use it in a `LIKE` query.

Comment: I was expecting your answer here :)

Comment: I get an error when I run your code, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword '`ESCAPE`'." (if I comment out from the word `ESCAPE` inclusive then it executes but obviously adds an unwanted `\`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the character with "\"?

```
UPDATE Mortgage 
SET TEXT = 'The interest rate is 7\%';
```

Comment: That merely updates the column with the value `'The interest rate is 7\%'` -- how does that help?

Comment: Set the escape char to be '\'

Comment: There is no `SET..ESCAPE` syntax!

Comment: No need, better luck next time -- I just upvoted a couple of your answers that are good ones :)

Answer (score 0):

What is your schema?

I tried this & it works(SQL-Server 2008 R2 & SSMS):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mortgage](
    [TEXT] [varchar](500) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
insert Mortgage (TEXT) values ('The interest rate is 7%');
SELECT TEXT FROM Mortgage;

UPDATE Mortgage SET TEXT = 'The new interest rate is 3%';
SELECT TEXT FROM Mortgage;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doubling the %: %%

```
UPDATE Mortgage 
SET TEXT = 'The interest rate is 7%%';
```