# Sql Server: How to search for literal percent character in like clause

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, escaping, criteria

I am using Hibernate Criteria with sql server 2000.  I want to use the `like` method to get records from the database that are literal `%`.  Can that be done?
example:

table base_target_unit:

```
id                                      code           name
8a91b32c3be0a5fe013c03cdb37f0002    13010410    户
8a91b32c3af8cd71013bd4fe06160044    12122609    %
8a91b32c3af8cd71013bd106e9dc002e    12122507    元/MB
402881b03a8c83ae013a8ca467f70041    12102399    亿分钟
402881b03a8c83ae013a8ca451610040    12102398    万分钟
402881b03a8c83ae013a8ca42cb3003f    12102397    万户
```

The sql I have is:

```
 select * from dbo.base_target_unit where name LIKE '%/%%' ESCAPE '/'
```

I want to get the record that name which is `%`.

Comment: See also this duplicate: [How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/).

Answer (score 2):

Use brackets. So to look for 88%

```
WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%88[%]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can escape the percent sign with the SQL LIKE function by using two percents (%%)**

This tells you more about how to do it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

```
select * from dbo.base_target_unit where name LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '%'
```

Comment: This is a use of the `ESCAPE` clause. When using the `ESCAPE` keyword, it is less confusing, in my opinion, to use a character that is not otherwise in the string. For example if the character `E` is not used, one could say `WHERE name LIKE 'E%' ESCAPE 'E'`. But that was already in the question (using `'/'`).