# Avoiding SQL Injection in PDO and using the like clause

Tags: sql, pdo

I am using prepared statements for a search functionality using PDO and I am using the like clause. Mysql is 5.5.32

```
function dblink(){
    # hidden #
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database", 
     $username, $password,  array(
     PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ
    ));
    return $conn;
}

$conn    = dblink();
$query   = "select * from tablename where attrib like ? ;";
$stmt    = $conn->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute(array($_POST['field']."%"));

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

This dumps all the table contents when user enters % for field in the html form. I thought prepared statement would handle it and there is % in execute so that it matches the substring entered.

How do I use the POST field as normal text only so that it doesn't cause such problem?

Comment: It looks like you can [replace `%` with `[%]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql) but this seems like a hack.

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer to this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683746/escaping-mysql-wild-cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This dumps all the table contents when user enters % for field in the html form.

Yes. That's the exact purpose of LIKE operator.
No, it has nothing to do with prepared statement. The latter is used to format your data, not to interfere with query logic.

If you don't like the way your code works - change it. But at the moment it works exactly the way you coded, with no flaws.

Comment: Ya i thought so too but didn't know if there was a better way.
So now i am using it like this:
 $stmt->execute(addcslashes(array($_POST['field']),"_%"));

Comment: I see no point in this replacement. Though it won't do any harm either

Comment: I did this so that if user enters % for field, it would be escaped. Without the change, the complete table was outputed using %

Comment: Well, user wants a whole table then. What's the problem?

Comment: Thats true. but I don't want the user to have that feature. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then you have to write some code that implements restrictions, not just escape arbitrary characters.