# How do I find ' % ' with the LIKE operator in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have a column name Address which consists of some address which has '%' in between as:

```
Address
--------------------
Aman Ja%lan%
Stree% Ro%ad
```

etc., etc.

How I can write the LIKE operator to find that pattern?

I tried:

```
declare @var char(1)
set @var='!%'
select Address from Accomodation where Address like '%'+@var+'%'
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I would use

```
WHERE columnName LIKE '%[%]%'
```

SQL Server stores string summary statistics for use in estimating the number of rows that will match a `LIKE` clause. The cardinality estimates can be better and lead to a more appropriate plan when the square bracket syntax is used.

The response to [this Connect Item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/680257/optimization-problem-on-a-query-with-two-similar-like-clauses-one-with-a-variable) states

> We do not have support for precise cardinality estimation in the
>   presence of user defined escape characters. So we probably get a poor
>   estimate and a poor plan. We'll consider addressing this issue in a
>   future release.

An example

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
X VARCHAR(50),
Y CHAR(2000) NULL
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON T(X)

INSERT INTO T (X)
SELECT TOP (5) '10% off'
FROM master..spt_values
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP (100000)  'blah'
FROM master..spt_values v1,  master..spt_values v2


SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE X LIKE '%[%]%'

SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE X LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Shows 457 logical reads for the first query and 33,335 for the second.

Comment: Indeed martin, very lucid explanation, but what about the case when one has to search ']'  ???

For example
`INSERT INTO T (X)
SELECT TOP (5) '10[] off'
FROM master..spt_values`

Comment: Indeed martin, very lucid explanation, but what about the case when one has to search ']'  ???

For example
`INSERT INTO T (X)
SELECT TOP (5) '10[] off'
FROM master..spt_values`

For this when i try to search with [], it did not come

`SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE X LIKE '%[]]%'`

But it worked with the below one
`SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE X LIKE '%\]%' ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: @TejuMB - That doesn't need escaping. Just use LIKE `'%]%'`. If you do `LIKE '%[AB]]%'` that means match a character in the set `A,B` then a `]`. If you do `LIKE '%[A]]%'` that means match `A]`. If you do `LIKE '%[]]%'` then it means "match a single character in this empty set of characters followed by a `]`. As the set is empty no character can ever match.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `ESCAPE`:

```
WHERE columnName LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d906/1)

Comment: Thanks , actually i removed ESCAPE as i thought it may be for my reference.

Comment: Using LIKE '%[%]%'  should the make trick too.

Comment: @491243 Actually, this is pretty good point. You are not able to escape ']' like this '[]]', but you can escape it using the the ESCAPE keyword and escape character. +1 for this and it is a pity there is no ESCAPE keyword for PATHINDEX too.

Comment: @gotqn - Why do you say you can't escape it like that? `SELECT 1 WHERE 'A[B' LIKE 'A[[]B'` works fine. Using `ESCAPE` can give worse plans as my answer shows.

Comment: @MartinSmith You are right. I was trying to say that you can not escape "close" bracket, but it seems that it is not special symbol and does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @var char(3)
set @var='[%]'
select Address from Accomodation where Address like '%'+@var+'%'
```

You must use [] cancels the effect of wildcard, so you read % as a normal character, idem about character _