# How to handle special characters in SQL Server Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in table

```
create table Manager(id int, managerid varchar(10) , managername varchar(50))

insert into Manager(id, managerid, managername)
values (1, 'A1', 'Mangesh'), (2, 'A''2', 'Sagar'), (3, '_C[%]3', 'Ah_mad'),
       (4, 'A4', 'Mango'), (5, 'B5', 'Sandesh')
```

I am using stored procedure to get the result on the basis of given characters. One of the users want to search with `c[%]`. I am able to handle `%` with `[%]` but if string is having `[%]` then I am unable to find it.

I tried with following query

```
declare @str varchar(100)='C[[%]'

SELECT m.* 
FROM Manager m 
WHERE m.managerid LIKE '%'+@str+'%'
```

This way I am able to get the result but in this case input is `C[%` only. I replaced `%` with `[%]` in my stored procedure parameter. But if input is `C[%]` then my query is not returning anything.

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you looking for managerid's that include c[%]? Have you tried charindex?

Comment: _"I am unable to do this"_ is not a problem description. What did you try? What happened? Why was that wrong?

Comment: Please include the code you used to search for `c[%]`. 
I suspect that you need to look for the `LIKE... ESCAPE` functionality though

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693349/how-do-i-find-with-the-like-operator-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
declare @str varchar(100)='C\[\%]'

SELECT m.* 
FROM Manager m 
WHERE m.managerid LIKE '%'+@str+'%' ESCAPE '\'
```

It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the square bracket and `%` character using `[]`, this tells SQL to treat them as literals.

So in order to find the `%` it needs escaped as `[%]`, the same for the square bracket it needs escaped as `[[]`

You don't need to escape the `]` because if it's not paired with `[` has no special meaning.

```
select * from Manager where managerid like '%c[[][%]]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Escape` to ignore the `wildcards`. Try this

```
select * from Manager 
where managerid like '%c\[%]%' escape '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape only one opening '['

```
SELECT * FROM MANAGER where managerid like '%_C[[%]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `%`, `_` and `[` are special characters and should be escaped. So it could be that even your INSERT-statement is wrong.

You can place the special characters between square brackets `[` and `]` to make them literal.

```
insert into Manager(id,managerid,managername)values(3,'[_]C[[][%]]3','Ah[_]mad')
```

You can use this same method to search on:

```
SELECT * FROM Manager
WHERE managerid LIKE '%C[[][%]]%'
```

Or define your own escape character like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Manager
WHERE managerid LIKE '%C\[\%]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Here is some documentation that might be usefull to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to searching with input **'C[%]'**. Check this answer,

```
declare @str varchar(100)='C[%]'

SELECT m.* 
FROM Manager m 
WHERE REPLACE(m.managerid,'[','')    LIKE  '%'+@str+'%'
```