# Would like to update a SQL Server table data by removing the special character "%" from all the records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in updating records in a table. Currently, I have a `%` value which I would like to remove from all the records. I have over 4000 records in this table.

```
Date       Server   CPU   MEM   DRVC
------------------------------------
01/10/10   DRV01    90%   80%   40%
```

I want to have the data values remain unchanged but "%" sign to be removed.

```
Date       Server   CPU   MEM   DRVC
------------------------------------
01/10/10   DRV01     90    80    40
```

In my case I need to update three column records

```
CPU
MEM
DRVC
```

```
declare @x = CPU
declare @y = MEM
declare @z = DRVC
SELECT REPLACE(@x, '%', '') from table01;
SELECT REPLACE(@y, '%', '') from table01;
SELECT REPLACE(@z, '%', '') from table01;
```

Comment: Have you written the `UPDATE` statement? This post should give you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693349/how-do-i-find-with-the-like-operator-in-sql-server

Comment: Now would be a good time to change those from varchar to numeric too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`REPLACE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function to remove it as

```
SELECT [Date],
       [Server],
       REPLACE([CPU], '%', '') [CPU],
       REPLACE([MEM], '%', '') [MEM],
       REPLACE([DRVC], '%', '') [DRVC]
FROM [table01];
```

The `REPLACE()` function replaces all occurrences of a specified string value (`'%'` in your case) with another string value.

The query will returns:

```
Date       Server   CPU   MEM   DRVC
------------------------------------
01/10/10   DRV01    90    80    40
```

If you really want to **[`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** your table as you mention in the title *"Would like to update a SQL Server table data by removing the special character “%” from all the records"* then

```
UPDATE [table01]
SET [CPU] = REPLACE([CPU], '%', ''),
    [MEM] = REPLACE([MEM], '%', ''),
    [DRVC] = REPLACE([DRVC], '%', '')
--WHERE <Type your conditions here>
```

Finally, you need to choose the right datatype for your columns, since `CPU`, `MEM` and `DRVC` are numeric values, then try to use a numeric datatype which is the proper way, you can use `INT`, `BIGINT`, `DECIMAL`... according to your requirement. See **[`Data types`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and **[`ALTER TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the REPLACE function...

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(100) = 'hello%world';
SELECT REPLACE(@x, '%', '')
```

Edit... adding code to explicitly show how to perform an actual UPDATE...

```
  -- create some test data...
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN DROP TABLE #TestData; END;

    CREATE TABLE #TestData (
        [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
        [Server] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        CPU VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
        MEM VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
        DRVC VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL 
        );
    INSERT #TestData (Date, Server, CPU, MEM, DRVC) VALUES
        (GETDATE(), 'DRV01', '90%', '80%', '40%');

    -- check the initial state of the test data.
    SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

    -- UPDATE the data to remove the % symbols.
    UPDATE td SET 
        td.CPU = REPLACE(td.CPU, '%', ''),
        td.MEM = REPLACE(td.MEM, '%', ''),
        td.DRVC = REPLACE(td.DRVC, '%', '')
    FROM
        #TestData td;

    -- check the post-update state of the test data.
    SELECT * FROM #TestData td;
```

Comment: sorry, guys, I am a beginner kindly correct me if I am making a mistake. In my case I need to update three column records
CPU
MEM
DRVC

declare @x = CPU
declare @y = MEM
declare @z = DRVC
SELECT REPLACE(@x, '%', '') from table01;
SELECT REPLACE(@y, '%', '') from table01;
SELECT REPLACE(@z, '%', '') from table01;

Comment: @StillLearning - I've updated my original answer to better illustrate how to write this into an actual UPDATE command.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE() function:

```
select replace('40%','%','')
```