# c# - using % as a text symbol(percent)

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I'm searching in DataTable

```
        DataRow[] found = table.Select(f_sep);
```

//table - DataTable, f_sep - string with a query that looks like: F_TEXT like '%some_word%'

In the query I need to use `%` as a percent(to find percent values). If in the query i write 5% it will return all results with 5 and other symbols after it, so I tried to replace %:

```
string stt = textBox.Text.Replace("%", "'%'");
```

I get an error - you can't use operator mod

```
Replace("%", "\"%\"");
```

I get an error using LIKE operator.

How can I replace % ?

Comment: Why not `"\"\%\""` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the % sign,

Use brackets. So to look for 75%

`WHERE MyCol LIKE '%75[%]%'`

source: [How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 2):

The escape sequence for % is [%]...always find that a bit odd but I'm sure there is a good reason.