# Like doesn't escape special characters NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

I have a problem with NHibernate LINQ `contains` method, because I want to escape special characters in the string for example if I type:

```
lel%lel
```

I want to find exactly

```
lel%lel but not lel4325234534lel
```

To find values I use following methods:

```
tabArray = _session.Query<Tab>()
                    .Where(x => x.attr.Contains(query))
                    .ToArray();
```

I also try using `likeexpression` but it also didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, that this should be up to us (our code) not NHibernate. We can use this:

[How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7191449/1679310)

i.e. replace any `%` in C# with **`[%]`**

```
lel[%]lel
```

And this would return what expected

```
.Where(x => x.attr.Contains(query)) // query == "lel[%]lel"
```

Comment: I think I try everything but the solution is so simple... Thank You!

Comment: Great if that helped! Enjoy awesome NHibernate ;)