# Problems with contains query for full text indexed column

Tags: sql-server

I have a column(HREFTopic) in a table (populartrends) which contains the following value:

http://twitter.com/search?q=%23DiaContraelCancerdeMama

The following query returns records.

```
 1. select * from populartrends where hreftopic like '%23DiaContraelCancerdeMama%'

 2.  select * from populartrends where  contains (hreftopic , 'DiaContraelCancerdeMama')
```

The following query doesnot return records:

```
 select * from populartrends where contains (hreftopic , '%23DiaContraelCancerdeMama')

 select * from populartrends where contains (hreftopic , '23DiaContraelCancerdeMama')
```

I am clueless as to why.

I tried this one

```
 select * from populartrends where contains (hreftopic , '[%]23DiaContraelCancerdeMama')
```

and I get Syntax error near '[' in the full-text search condition '[%]23DiaContraelCancerdeMama'.

Comment: You need to escape the '%' if you're trying to search for that symbol.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql  `[ ]`