# Replace a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i need to replace a string %%firstName%% by [contact.FirstName] and %%lastName%% by [contact.LastName], however these strings can be found on any position in the field
example

> Welcome Aboard %%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%% %%firstname%% %%lastname%%

i need this to become

> Welcome Aboard %%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%% [contact.FirstName] [contact.LastName]

note that the first `%%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%%` remain unchanged

using below query will look for first occurence of %%first..%% and drop the rest

```
> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; SELECT SUBJECT,
>   REPLACE((CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(SUBJECT, CHARINDEX('%%', SUBJECT) + 1,
> LEN(SUBJECT) - CHARINDEX('%%', SUBJECT) - CHARINDEX('%%',
> REVERSE(SUBJECT)) ) LIKE '%Firstname%' OR SUBSTRING(SUBJECT,
> CHARINDEX('%%', SUBJECT) + 1, LEN(SUBJECT) - CHARINDEX('%%', SUBJECT)
> - CHARINDEX('%%', REVERSE(SUBJECT)) ) LIKE '%First name%'     THEN REPLACE (SUBJECT, SUBSTRING(SUBJECT, CHARINDEX('%%', SUBJECT) + 1,
> LEN(SUBJECT) - CHARINDEX('%%', SUBJECT) - CHARINDEX('%%',
> REVERSE(SUBJECT)) ),'[Contact.First Name]') ELSE SUBJECT END),'%','')
> 
> FROM CAMPAIGN




CREATE TABLE #tab ( SUBJECT VARCHAR (100))
   INSERT INTO #tab
   SELECT 'Welcome Aboard %%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%% %%firstname%% %%lastname%%'
   SELECT * FROM #tab
   DROP TABLE #tab
```

by running this query, i can isolate the string between the %% %%

```
SELECT  SUBJECT
        ,   SUBSTRING(
                        SUBJECT, 
                        CHARINDEX('%%', SUBJECT) + 1, 
                        LEN(SUBJECT) - CHARINDEX('%%', SUBJECT) - CHARINDEX('%%', REVERSE(SUBJECT))

                    )

FROM #tab
```

[image of Result in SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5of6.png)

Comment: Your problem starts at the moment that you selected to use "%" as placeholder delimiter. IN SQL, this is equivalent to "*" (meaning, **_ANYTHING_**). Change that delimiter to something that is considered as a character in SQL.

Comment: The other problem is that SQL isn't meant to generate text. That's the job of report generators and client-side code. It's a *LOT* easier to do such things in a report, or even with string replacement in C#.

Comment: Hi guys. thanks for your feedback... @Panagiotis, i have been mandated to do it in the DB

Comment: @FDavidov by using the substring and %%, it allow me to isolate the strings within the %%, but can't get the REPLACE to change them to what i need

Comment: Again, in SQL when you write `'%ABC%'` (or with two `%%` for that matter) it means `"whatever you want to put here ABC plus whatever you want to put here too'`. The '%` is a wildcard in SQL and hence your issue (at least one of them). You could use something else, like `'^^firstname^^'` or `'$$'` or `'??'` instead.

Comment: @FDavidov
the table contain these %% characters after data migration and now trying to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place you're going to have problems is if you're using a **WHERE** clause with %. **REPLACE** just replaces the found substring with another substring.

Let's start with this. I've put %%firstname%% and %%lastname%% in different places.

```
CREATE TABLE #tab
(
    SUBJECT VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT #tab select 'Welcome Aboard %%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%% %%firstname%% %%lastname%%'
INSERT #tab select 'Welcome Aboard %%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%%%%lastname%% %%firstname%% test here'
INSERT #tab select 'Welcome Aboard %%firstname%%%%lastname%% %%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%%'
INSERT #tab select 'Welcome Aboard %%firstname%% %%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%% %%lastname%%'
INSERT #tab select 'Welcome Aboard'
```

You could just do this:

```
UPDATE #tab set [SUBJECT]=REPLACE(REPLACE([SUBJECT], '%%firstname%%', '[contact.FirstName]'), '%%lastname%%', '[contact.LastName]')
```

If you want a WHERE clause, you'll have to escape the %: [How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql)

```
UPDATE #tab set [SUBJECT]=REPLACE(REPLACE([SUBJECT], '%%firstname%%', '[contact.FirstName]'), '%%lastname%%', '[contact.LastName]')
WHERE [SUBJECT] LIKE '%[%][%]%name[%][%]%'
```

Comment: Thanks!
now in the case when i have this
`INSERT #tab select 'Welcome Aboard %%specialfield2|fallback=||||||%% %%firstname%% %%lastname|fallback=1234343%%'`
i also want to change the `%%lastname|fallback=1234343%%` to `[contact.lastname]`

Comment: yikes. So, that will require some extra stuff that is harder to do than in the just comments :) Take a look at this: http://toyboxcreations.net/2005/03/string-manipulation-replace-patindex-and-regular-expressions/

Comment: Ok, so I couldn't stop thinking about it, so here's a sql fiddle that solves it using PATINDEX. Not optimized at all. [http://rextester.com/VRY81692](http://rextester.com/VRY81692). Can I get an accepted answer ;)?

Comment: Thank you. that's what i ended up doing :)