# Filter out column values that start with %

Tags: sql, sql-server

Since the percentage sign (%) is the wild card in SQL I am having trouble with filtering by values in a column that actually start with %.

```
Select *
From customer
Where last_name not like '%%'
```

I have some weird customer instances where the last names are %Smith, %Johnson, etc. I don't want to remove the %, I just want those instances to not be returned in my result set.

Comment: Here is a similar question asked before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql

Comment: Thanks, I tried to find an existing answer first but was not successful

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to escape this by using square brackets around the given character(s) that you want to escape :

```
SELECT *
  FROM Customer
 WHERE last_name NOT LIKE '[%]%'
```