# PATINDEX, wildcards and variables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, wildcard, patindex

How do you get `PATINDEX` to to do a wildcard card match on a variable that includes a `%` character?

In the following I want `PATINDEX` to return the starting position of '%3d':

```
DECLARE @inputText as VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @s as Int   
DECLARE @cIn as CHAR(3)

SET @inputText = 'OEi49j3DNxE%3d'
SET @cIn = '%3d'
SET @s = PATINDEX('%' + @cIn +'%', @InputText)
```

As you can see from the `@InputText`, this starts at position 12.

> OEi49j3DNxE **%3d**

However `PATINDEX` seems to return the start position at 7 because it seems to drop the `%` from `CIn`:

> OEi49j**3D**NxE%3d

How do I get look for `%3d` as specified, rather than `3d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the % sign by wrapping with [].  In order to do this you will have to make your variable @cIn larger to accommodate the extra 2 characters and just do a replace before you do the patindex or you can do it inline without changing variable sizes.

```
DECLARE @inputText as VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @s as Int   
DECLARE @cIn as CHAR(5)

SET @inputText = 'OEi49j3DNxE%3d'
SET @cIn = '%3d'
SET @cIn = REPLACE(@cIn, '%', '[%]')
SET @s = PATINDEX('%' + @cIn +'%', @InputText)
```

OR

```
DECLARE @inputText as VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @s as Int   
DECLARE @cIn as CHAR(5)

SET @inputText = 'OEi49j3DNxE%3d'
SET @cIn = '%3d'
SET @s = PATINDEX('%' + replace(@cIn, '%', '[%]') +'%', @InputText)
```

You can read more about here: [How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql)

Comment: Voted as answer as the alternative option provided worked for me (`cIn` is being used elsewhere, and storing it as `[%]3d` causes other problems). Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use square brackets:

```
SET @cIn = '[%]3d'
```

---

```
select 
   without_brackets = patindex('%'+'%3d'+'%','OEi49j3DNxE%3d')
 , with_brackets    = patindex('%'+'[%]3d'+'%','OEi49j3DNxE%3d')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BVA62284

returns:

```
+------------------+---------------+
| without_brackets | with_brackets |
+------------------+---------------+
|                7 |            12 |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Totally correct - only went with @Avitus as the alternative provided worked better in my full code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @inputText as VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @s as Int   
DECLARE @cIn as CHAR(3)

SET @inputText = 'OEi49j3DNxE%3d'
SET @cIn = '[%]3d'
SET @s = PATINDEX('%' + @cIn + '%' , @InputText)

select @s
```

Output: 12

Comment: Correct, thank you very much - only went with @Avitus as the alternative provided worked better in my full code. Thanks.