# get all columns containing % as its one of the letter in SQL

Tags: sql

Lets say I got a table Student with a column name as Student_Name. Table looks like :

### Student

```
Student_Name
------------
abc
xyz
a%xw
p%ghjk
```

Can someone pls help me in writing a sql query to fetch all rows containing % in between ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LIKE` with the `ESCAPE` option:

```
where student_name like '%$%%' escape '$'
```

If you want characters on either side, then use the `'_'` wildcard:

```
where student_name like '%_$%_%' escape '$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need the ESCAPE option unless you want to use a different escape character than the default which is '\'.

In this case you can simply do:

```
WHERE student_name LIKE '%\%%'
```