# How do I find specific symbol+character combo in T-SQL specifically using LIKE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have messy data that needs some cleaning, and, amongst other pattern matching, I am trying to remove any that is like: '-c[^ROAEH]'.

From another similar question, I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM #AcctKeysInt
WHERE NewCustName LIKE '[!-c][^ROAEH]'
ESCAPE '!'
```

Also:

```
SELECT *
FROM #AcctKeysInt
WHERE NewCustName LIKE '[-c]%[^ROAEH]'
```

And obviously the common:

```
SELECT *
FROM #AcctKeysInt
WHERE NewCustName LIKE '[-]c[^ROAEH]'
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM #AcctKeysInt
WHERE NewCustName LIKE '%[-]c[^ROAEH]'
```

Basically, I cannot manage to include the hyphen into the character search, as I get returned results without the string beginning with '-c' specifically.

**I have done other pattern matching cleansing on this data, where '-' has been found,** however not with the `LIKE` operator, so I wonder if there is a way to do it with the `LIKE`?
For context, here's some of the other pattern matching code to clear out data that i've used:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AccountKeysCleansed;
SELECT strAcctNbrCurrent
       ,strAcctNbrHistoric
       ,strCustName
       ,CustNameOld
       ,GarbageOld
       ,IntCustName
       ,IntGarbage
       ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('- c', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('- c', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-cl', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('-cl', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*CAS', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('*CAS', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*CLOS', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('*CLOS', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('* CLOS', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('* CLOS', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-  cl', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('-  cl', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*pend CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('*pend CLOSE', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('- To CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('- To CLOSE', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-To CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('-To CLOSE', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-=CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('-=CLOSE', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('(CLOSE',IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('(CLOSE', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*deceas',IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('*deceas', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-deceas',IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('-deceas', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*legal',IntCustName) > 0 THEN TRIM(LEFT(IntCustName, CHARINDEX('*legal', IntCustName) - 1))
             WHEN IntCustName LIKE '*%' THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - 1)
             ELSE IntCustName END NewCustName
       ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('- c', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('- c', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-cl', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('-cl', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*CAS', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('*CAS', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*CLOS', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('*CLOS', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('* CLOS', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('* CLOS', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-  cl', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('-  cl', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*pend CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('*pend CLOSE', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('- To CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('- To CLOSE', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-To CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('-To CLOSE', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-=CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('-=CLOSE', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('(CLOSE', IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('(CLOSE', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*deceas',IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('*deceas', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('-deceas',IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('-deceas', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN CHARINDEX('*legal',IntCustName) > 0 THEN RIGHT(IntCustName, LEN(IntCustName) - CHARINDEX('*legal', IntCustName) + 1) + IntGarbage
             WHEN IntCustName LIKE '*%' THEN '*' + IntGarbage
             ELSE IntGarbage END newGarbage
INTO   #AccountKeysCleansed
FROM   #AccountKeysInt;
```

To put an example, some of the custnames I am trying to clear have names such as:

- "Name Surname-cro"
- "Random-Name-cah"
- "RandomName-caird"
- "Name-universal-Surname-coh"
  ... and so on. So I want SQL to find '-c[ROAEH]', to then add anything right of '-' to the pile of (column) Garbage.

Do you know how can I do this with the `LIKE` operator?

Comment: You only need the square bracket syntax to denote that a single character must be a set or a range. if the square bracket contains a `-` between two other characters then it will be interpreted as a range so you would list it at the end if you wanted to match a set containing that. But when you want to match a single character it doesn't need to be in square brackets anyway. Your main problem seems to be that you have `^ROAEH` but need `ROAEH` - including the `^` matches any character **not** in the following set.

Comment: @MartinSmith the reason I used the square brackets to search for the hyphen ```[-]``` was because of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql I thought it suggested square bracketing it should precisely look for the symbol escaping the common SQL premises of it being a range? Maybe I did it wrong altogether

Comment: That question is about escaping a `%`. This behaves oppositely than `-`. The `%` has special significance **unless** in square brackets. The `-` has no special significance **except** when in square brackets

Comment: @MartinSmith That makes more sense now -  thank you!! As you can tell I am quite new. And it worked now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you're looking for the pattern '%-c[roaeh]%'

```
SELECT *
FROM #AcctKeysInt
WHERE NewCustName LIKE '%-c[roaeh]%'
```

Such pattern also works with [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql)

```
PATINDEX('%-c[roaeh]%', IntCustName)
```